# Make new tab page wait until main page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have page `main.php`

When on `main.php` button is clicked it submits form with `PHP $_POST`

On that button click in new window I open `print.php`

The question is how can I make `print.php` wait (not load) until `main.php` has fully loaded after form is done and page refreshed using javascript/jquery?

I tried using

```
window.open('print?id='+'<?=$id;?>'+'&view=scoring', '_blank');
```

after `main.php` refresh it does not work as popup is blocked

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

P.S. I know I could use ajax to submit data without refresh but it is not an option at this time.

Comment: You can't make it "wait to load". At most you could make it load some placeholder content first, and then replace that with something else later. But you would still need to find a way to "access" your popup window, after the main page has reloaded.

Comment: What _exactly_ do you need to achieve here?

Comment: @CBroe On button click I submit form. And at same time I need to open other link in  new tab with info for printing. If main page reloads I cant use `window.open` as no human click results in blocked popup

Comment: If I could open it without popup blocked after reload it would be all fine. .. Issue is that form saves new data and if I open new tab on click the data in print page will be outdated

Comment: You won't get around the popup blockers in current browsers with that, no. Does it absolutely have to be a popup window - or could you perhaps just create an `iframe` inside the reloaded main page, and load the print.php in there? (And maybe put it into an "overlay" that the user can close when they are done with it.)

Comment: @CBroe Modal version is an option but only if nothing else can do the trick. But If I make modal I could also submit form with ajax. Needed the fastest solution!

Comment: Not sure if there is anything quicker, resp. that could be implemented with less re-working of the process. The form submission could target the popup in the first place, and then the popup reloads its opener, if necessary - but then you would have to transfer the whole data processing into the script that gets opened in the popup. // Having the windows "communicate" via `postMessage` would only work from in direction popup -> main window here I think (because after reloading the main window, you lose the reference to the popup), so the popup could only "poll" for completion then.